# Filter and sort items of a generic list in Java

Tags: java, collections, guava

I'm implementing search, sorting and pagination logic for a web application and I need to find an efficient and possibly not verbose way to sort and filter items of a generic type list (`List<T>`). I would like to dynamally pass the field by which the list will be sorted (as a string, for example).

Is it a good idea to use Guava libraries or can I achieve the same result using standard java libraries? I've never used Guava and I would avoid adding additional libraries to my project if I'll going to use them only for minor utilities.

Note I'm also using Spring in my project. Is there some helpful utility to handle collections?

In .NET applications I usually use LINQ to manupulate and query collections, I'd like to find something similar or at least a simple alternative to this approach... can you help me?

**NOTE**
I need to **sort** custom objects by an arbitrary field, so if I have a `Person` object with `name`, `surname` and `age` fields, I need to sort the list by one of these.

Comment: Well if I am not mistaken Guava is open-source therefore you can look under the hood and check how they implement theirs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Java libraries provide `Collections.sort()` for one-shot sorting and `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` for permanently sorted collections.

Either the objects inside the collections need to implement comparable (in which case the default behavior of all of the above is to sort using natural ordering) or you can specify a `Comparator` to the sort operation (or `Tree*`). If you do specify a `Comparator` it over-rides the default sorting behavior and completely replaces it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom `Comparator` for sorting. When you do write your comparator, you can then use the `Collections.sort()` method to sort it in the manner which is defined in the `compare()` method. 
The `compare()` method should be in like with the `equals()` method. As in. if two objects are equals then they should compare to be equal.

**Straight from the Java Docs.**

Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

One, way of doing it based on 3 different parameters is also, to write 3 different comparators,

```
public class FirstNameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

    public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
        return person1.getFirstName().compareTo(person2.getFirstName());
    }

public class LastNameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

    public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
        return person1.getLastName().compareTo(person2.getLastName());
    }
```

Now, when you sort your collection of List using the Collections.sort() method signature which takes a userdefined comparator to sort the list.

Which would be

```
Collections.sort(persons, new LastNameComparator());
```

assuming persons is the list of persons.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort will handle the sorting just fine.

In case of filtering as long as Comparator, hashcode/equals will do just fine with a TreeSet, etc.

Guava does the same thing, anyhow having guava is good also, since this library contains way more then just collections.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to the (great) answers here, with Java8 you can use the comparator in the following way:         `myPersons.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyPerson::getAge));`

Full code I wrote for example:

```
public class Java8Comparator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<MyPerson> myPersons = getPersons();

        System.out.println("Before Sort...");
        myPersons.forEach(myPerson ->
                System.out.println("Person: " + myPerson.getFirstName() + " with salary: " + myPerson.getSalary() + " and age: " + myPerson.getAge()));

        myPersons.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyPerson::getAge));
        myPersons.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyPerson::getFirstName));
        myPersons.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyPerson::getSalary));

        System.out.println("After Sort...");
        myPersons.forEach(myPerson ->
                System.out.println("Person: " + myPerson.getFirstName() + " with salary: " + myPerson.getSalary() + " and age: " + myPerson.getAge()));
    }

    private static List<MyPerson> getPersons() {
        List<MyPerson> result = new ArrayList<>();

        result.add(new MyPerson("saul", new BigDecimal("86000"), 54));
        result.add(new MyPerson("mahmud", new BigDecimal("67000"), 21));
        result.add(new MyPerson("hillary", new BigDecimal("120000"), 46));
        result.add(new MyPerson("mickel", new BigDecimal("180000"), 25));
        result.add(new MyPerson("donald", new BigDecimal("140000"), 17));

        return result;
    }
}

class MyPerson {

    private String firstName;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private int age;

    public MyPerson(String firstName, BigDecimal salary, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```